# What is the output of time command in Linux

Tags: linux, time

> 0m0.043s

This is what is obtained out of time command in Linux. Is that 0.043 milliseconds or 0.043 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output you have provided:

```
0m0.043s
```

That `s` at the end stands for seconds; similarly that `m` more to the left side of the number stands for minutes. So `0.043` can be interpreted mathematically as milliseconds since it is clearly a fraction of a second. And as explained in the fine manual page for [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time); emphasis is mine:

> time - get time in **seconds**

Additionally, if you ever need to look up info on a Unix/Linux command you can just use [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man) to get the manual pages for that tool like this:

```
man time
```

Comment: It is 0.043 seconds, so can't be interpreted as milliseconds - you'd have to multiply it up first - 43ms.